# Using PIVOT in sql

Tags: sql, pivot

I have following `TypeStatusDetails` table. This table has different `TypeID`s. Each type can have max 4 `StatusID`s (or less i.e. for eg. `TypeID` 3 has only 3 `StatusID`s).

RecordCount shows no. of records for specific StatusID.
(eg. 3 Pending Records for Type_1)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
TypeID    Type      StatusID     StatusName    RecordCount
---------------------------------------------------------------
1         Type_1      1          Pending         3
1         Type_1      2         In Process       2
1         Type_1      3         Completed        1
1         Type_1      4         Invalid          1
2         Type_2      1          Pending         4
2         Type_2      2         In Process       5
2         Type_2      3         Completed        6
2         Type_2      4         Invalid          1
3         Type_3      1          Pending         1
3         Type_3      2        In Process        1
3         Type_3      3        Completed         1
```

I want result as following table:

Depending on each Type, I want to display RecordCount as per status with StatusID.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Type Type  Status  Pending   Status  InProcess  Status  Completed Status Invalid         ID          ID     Count       ID     Count      ID      Count     ID     Count
            for               for                for               for
          Pending           InProcess          Completed          Invalid
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  Type_1     1       3        2         2         3         1       4       1
2  Type_2     1       4        2         5         3         6       4       1
3  Type_3     1       1        2         1         3         1       4       0
```

I have used following query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       TypeID,Type,StatusName,RecordCount
    FROM #TypeStatusDetails
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(RecordCount)
    FOR StatusName IN ([Pending],[In Process],[Completed],[Invalid]) 
)AS pvt
```

But I am having trouble to get StatusId column as per each StatusName to combine it in pivot.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Your RDMBS is SQL Server I assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT TypeID, Type,
       Coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Pending' THEN StatusID END),0) AS [Status for Pending],
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Pending' THEN RecordCount ELSE 0 END) AS [Pending],
       Coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'In Process' THEN StatusID END),0) AS [Status for In Process],
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'In Process' THEN RecordCount ELSE 0 END) AS [In Process],
       Coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Completed' THEN StatusID END),0) AS [Status for Completed],
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Completed' THEN RecordCount ELSE 0 END) AS [Completed],
       Coalesce(MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Invalid' THEN StatusID END),0) AS [Status for Invalid],
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Invalid' THEN RecordCount ELSE 0 END) AS [Invalid]
FROM TypeStatusDetails
GROUP BY TypeID, Type

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using *conditional aggregation* instead of `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT TypeID, Type,  
       MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Pending' THEN StatusID END) AS [Status for Pending],
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Pending' THEN RecordCount ELSE 0 END) AS [Pending],
       MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'In Process' THEN StatusID END) AS [Status for In Process],
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'In Process' THEN RecordCount ELSE 0 END) AS [In Process],
       MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Completed' THEN StatusID END) AS [Status for Completed],
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Completed' THEN RecordCount ELSE 0 END) AS [Completed],
       MAX(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Invalid' THEN StatusID END) AS [Status for Invalid],
       SUM(CASE WHEN StatusName = 'Invalid' THEN RecordCount ELSE 0 END) AS [Invalid]
FROM TypeStatusDetails
GROUP BY TypeID, Type
```

The above query is standard ANSI SQL and can be used in any RDMBS.

Comment: *"[...]can be used in any RDMBS"* >> Except for the brackets around the column names.

Comment: Can we use If inside case to hanle recordcount 0 condition

Comment: @ Amita Just use `Coalesce` around the `max` functions

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos Thanks for Solution :)

Comment: @Amita Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.